# Opening unzipped files(new to Ubuntu)

Tags: 20.04

I'm new to this ubuntu and I just downloaded and unzipped a file. I did the extraction succesfully and I can see the new extracted files. But I don't know what I'm supposed to do to open the application.I just got a bunch of files and I don't know what to do now.Currently using 20.04

Comment: what is this 'zip' file you refer to?

Comment: Insufficient data. Look for a README file in the zip. Maybe it needs to be compiled. Maybe it needs to be placed somewhere. Maybe lots of possiblites. For new users, we generally don't recommend installing software this way.

Comment: Zip file is just a form of packaging multiple files into one file, so it's easier to transfer, store etc. What to do with the extracted files depends on what these files actually are. It's no difference as if you would receive these files in already extracted form, eg. someone would give them to you on a USB stick.